# CSS: How to get straight border-bottom with a border radius to a div tag

Tags: html, css, border

I want a div element to have curved border with a specific value of border-radius and a straight border-bottom. 
If I use the border radius, the radius is also applied to the bottom border. Below image shows how bottom border has a radius.

[image]

My current css snippet:

```
.post-list {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: transparent;
        background: rgb(36, 27, 29);
        padding: 1rem 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(23, 9, 9);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

I want a straight bottom border but curved border for the div. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Please share your html code also.So, I can understand more and help you.Also, did you try <hr> tag below your post-list class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you try to achieve, but as I understood, the easiest way would be two nested div:

```css
#outerDiv {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#innerDiv {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outerDiv">
  <div id="innerDiv">Here be Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. It was damn easy. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want a border radius at the bottom you can set only top boarders using `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` like this:

```css
.post-list {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        border-left-color: transparent;
        background: rgb(36, 27, 29);
        padding: 1rem 0;
        padding-left: 10px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(23, 9, 9);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: white;
        border-top-left-radius: 25px;
        border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    }
```

```html
<div class= "post-list">
hello world
</div>
```